# Google Apps Scripts Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I brought up this question in one of my Google Admin groups and was referred here so hopefully I'm where I'm supposed to be!

Here's my issue.  If I include I go to Apps Scripts inside of my Manage Site page (under Sites), I get to the project page and there I can choose to open a new script from a template.  Inside the Script Gallery, no matter which script I choose to "Install", I get the error stating "File name cannot be empty".  I'm sure I'm making some kind of dumb mistake but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Unfortunately I can't say specifically when it started.  If anyone can steer me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.  I was going to attach an image but I don't have 10 posts....

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Script Gallery should only be accessible through Google Spreadsheets, not in Google Sites. If you are seeing that option in Google Sites please post a screenshot so we can see (using another image hosting service if you don't have enough reputation).